# How can I remain collapsed comments when I use Android Studio ？

Tags: android-studio

I'm using  Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023.

I hope to remain collapsed comments in Code A by deafult, so I have checked both *"Documentation comments"* and *"Multiline comments"*, you can see Image A.

But the comment in Code A always expends when the project is re-opened in Android Studio.

BWT, the region in Code B can remain collapsed when  the project is re-opened  if I checked "*Custom folding regions "*.

What's matter with my operation?

**Code A**

```
   /*
       The comment 1
       The comment 2
   */
```

**Code B**

```
//region Operate  Record
    private val mUIApp = appContext as UIApp
    private val _recordingState= MutableStateFlow(ERecordState.STOPPED)
//endregion
```

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Code A it seems that you are using multiline comments and currently android studio does not have a feature that lets you collapse multiline comments but in Code B you are using inline comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).